# How to return a variable from iOS native code to C# through an out parameter?

Tags: c#, ios, c, unity-game-engine, mono

Here's a little code snippet of a function that's supposed to return an integer value (42) from iOS native code to C# through an out parameter:

**iOS code:**

```
extern "C" {
    void _GetInt(int intVal) {
        intVal = 42;
    }
}
```

**C# code (Mono/Unity):**

```
[DllImport("__Internal")]
private static extern void _GetInt([Out] int retVal);

public static void getInt() {
    int intVal = 1234;
    if (Application.platform == RuntimePlatform.IPhonePlayer) {
        _GetInt(intVal); 
        Debug.Log("intVal: "+intVal);
    }
}
```

Now, when getInt() is called, intVal's value stays at 1234, rather then becoming 42.

Do you know what's wrong here? Shouldn't the declaration of "[Out] int retVal" be sufficient for mono to copy intVal's value back? Unfortunately the [docs](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/advanced/pinvoke/) don't explain it in enough detail, so your help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks more like C/C++ function than Object-C.

Anyways, *to modify a value from parameter, you have to pass it as a reference or pointer*.

You are passing it as a value right now. Google *"C++ pass by value, reference and pointer"*. When making plugins, it is better to use pointers instead of references if you want the parameter to be modified.

For C# use `out` instead of `[Out]`. There are difference between them and `[Out]` is slower in terms of performance especially when passing an array because the compiler will be doing some stuff automatically for you.

*C++*: (Notice `*` before `intVal`):

```
extern "C" {
    void _GetInt(int *intVal) {
        *intVal = 42;
    }
}
```

*C#*:

```
[DllImport("__Internal")]
private static extern void _GetInt(out int retVal);
```

Finally, judging by your last question, I suggest you learn C and C++ before you continue with your plugin. Understand pointers, allocating and de-allocating memory, pass by value, reference or pointer. If you don't, you will likely end of with memory leaks and some undefined behavior in your game.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation! Especially that little detail about out and [Out] is very valuable. Btw., you're right, it's c code, I just wanted to keep the example at a bare minimum. Also thank you for your advise about learning the basics of C/C++ first. See, the thing is, I have a clear understanding about pointers, reference, C/C++ - even Assembly. My problem roots in the lack of knowledge about what's going on in C# when marshaling. Unfortunately Mono's docs ain't very helpful in that regard. So again, thank you for the detailed explanation!

Comment: Ok. You are good to go then. The mono doc is useful when marshaling variables that are inside a class in C++. This is not the case here since you just want to modify the variable in the parameter. Although, the whole marshaling stuff is slow. I avoid them and simply use functions to set and get the variables.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
[DllImport("__Internal")]
private static extern void _GetInt([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I8, Out()] out int retVal);
```

Here's a list of more `UnmanagedType`'s: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.unmanagedtype(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Kyle, thank you for sharing this! Still the same issue though... Btw, there seems to be a ')' missing behind ".I8". Do you have any other ideas? Maybe it's related to Mono/Unity?